# How to get response from node-xmpp request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, xmpp, ejabberd

I learned to make request with the XMPPserver by using node-xmpp library. Now i can make the request as mentioned in XMPP extensions documentations. But now i want to get the callback response for the each request (especially the XML response).

Here i have used the following code the make a request subscription (friend request) to a another user

```
var net = require("net");
var xmpp = require('node-xmpp');

var cl = new xmpp.Client({ jid: "one@localhost",  password: "comet123$" })

cl.addListener('online', function(data) {
    console.log('Connected as ' + data.jid.user + '@' + data.jid.domain + '/' + data.jid.resource)

//making subscription
    var stanza = new xmpp.Element('presence',{
                      to: "hai@localhost",
                      from: "one@localhost",
                      type: "subscribe",
                             }).up
// making request
        cl.send(stanza);

    // nodejs has nothing left to do and will exit
    cl.end()
})
```

I want to know, how to get the response result.

I tried with the callback functionality with as llike this,

```
cl.send(stanza, function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

and also like this

```
var result = cl.send(stanza);
```

This returns only true,

So can anyone please tell me how do I get the callback result for the requests that we make by using the node-xmpp libarary

Answer (score 0):

There is no callback or return for XMPP messages. You will have to have to set up an event listener to pick up messages coming back from the server. Add:

```
cl.on('stanza', function(stanza){
  // Do something with the stanza

  // If you want to end after the first message you get back, move this here
  cl.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get raw data from connection

```
cl.connection.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log('data', data.toString('utf8'));
});
```